# How to define multiple nested states with different parents but the same templates

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i make an mobile site for buy/renew/transfer/ domains.

The whole app has 4 templates connected into functional chain.

```
Buy     :   Search -> (login if needed?) -> Pay -> -Confirmation
Renew   :   Choose -> (login if needed?) -> Pay -> -Confirmation
Transfer:   Choose -> (login if needed?) -> Pay -> -Confirmation
```

While the app has the same templates, the functionality and titles are different. And i want to be able to check the parent state within every state in order to make dynamic changes, and switch request strings.

The simplest way is to define 12 (4X3) routes in my `stateProvider`. but i'm looking for more effective way to do this by unite `buy.search, renew.search, transfer.search` and others in three groups of routes. is it possible? Do any one may suggest me other approach?

Thanks

===UPDATE===

current stateProvider

```
 .state('app.buy.search', {
              url: "/search",
              templateUrl: "templates/search_domain.html",
              controller: 'SearchCtrl'})

 .state('app.buy.login', {
              url: "/buy/login",
              templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
              controller: 'LoginCtrl'})

 .state('app.buy.pay', {
              url: "/buy/pay",
              templateUrl: "templates/pay.html",
              controller: 'PayCtrl'})

.state('app.renew.search', {
              url: "/search",
              templateUrl: "templates/search_domain.html",
              controller: 'SearchCtrl'})

 .state('app.renew.login', {
              url: "/buy/login",
              templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
              controller: 'LoginCtrl'})

 .state('app.renew.pay', {
              url: "/buy/pay",
              templateUrl: "templates/pay.html",
              controller: 'PayCtrl'})

.state('app.transfer.search', {
              url: "/search",
              templateUrl: "templates/search_domain.html",
              controller: 'SearchCtrl'})

 .state('app.transfer.login', {
              url: "/buy/login",
              templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
              controller: 'LoginCtrl'})

 .state('app.transfer.pay', {
              url: "/buy/pay",
              templateUrl: "templates/pay.html",
              controller: 'PayCtrl'})
```

Comment: post your current stateprovider configuration for better understanding

Comment: @Asik Done! Just as an example

Comment: Cheeck this pluncker http://plnkr.co/edit/NGsZJB?p=preview . you can reduce it as 3 configurations instead of 12 configurations..pass the module in URL but state is remains same. Also, you can get the current module param in controller if you need means

Comment: @Asik Ok, this actually a good idea. i can even make the module value as a variable and manage it outside in service. I'll try it, thanks!

Comment: Shall I add this as a answer

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the router configurations by applying `dynamic url`. In your case, pages (search, pay, login) are same for modules  (buy, renew, transfer). So you can change the configuration as follows

```
        $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
          url: '/',
          templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .state('app.search', {
          url: '{module}/search',
          views: {
            "searchView": {
              templateUrl: 'search.html',
              controller: 'SearchCtrl'
            }
          }
        })
        .state('app.pay', {
          url: '{module}/pay',
          views: {
            "payView": {
              templateUrl: 'pay.html',
              controller: 'PayCtrl'
            }
          }
        })
        .state('app.login', {
          url: '{module}/login',
          views: {
            "loginView": {
              templateUrl: 'login.html',
              controller: 'LoginCtrl'
            }
          }
        })
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/NGsZJB?p=preview